# printing two different integers at the end

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that creates a game that simulates flipping a coin.  I want to ask the user how many times the coin should be tossed.  Based on the response, the program should choose a number that is either 0 (heads) or 1 (tails) for that specified number of times.  I want it to print something like this: "[heads, tails, 'heads', 'heads']: there were 3 heads and 2 tails"

This is my code so far:

```
import random
#this function creates a game that simulates a coin
#I will ask how many times that the coin should be tossed
def coinToss():
    number = input("How many times do you want to flip the coin?: ")
    myList = []
    counter = 0
        for element in range(number):
            flip = random.randint(0, 1)
            if flip == 0:
                myList.append("Heads")
            else:
                myList.append("Tails")


print(str(myList)) + str(":there were ") + str(counter) + str(" Heads ") + str(" and ") + str(counter) + str(" Tails")
```

I have my variable counter, but how do I add up the heads and tails?  Very confused.  Sorry if this might sound to easy to you.  I know my print at the end is going to be wrong.

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: @Haidro: yeah, I just had a moment. Erasing history of this ever happening

Comment: try `myList.count("Heads")`

Comment: well I'm pretty sure it is.

Comment: @RyanErickson In python 2, you don't actually need parenthesis around your `print` *statement*. In python 3, it is a *function*, so you do need parentheses. Also, you should be using `raw_input()` in python 2, and using `int()` to convert from a string to an integer :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of appending `"heads"` or `"tails"` to `myList`, append the numbers:

```
for element in range(number):
    flip = random.randint(0, 1)
    myList.append(flip)
```

Now when you go to your print statement, you can use `sum()` and `len()`:

```
print "There were {} heads and {} tails".format(len(myList) - sum(myList), sum(myList))
```

As your list will consist of something like `[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]` (example), doing the length minus the sum will give you the amount of zeroes (heads), while getting the sum will give you the amount of ones (tails).

Using string formatting is much more neater :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
myList.count("Heads")
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that function!

Comment: You're welcome Ryan.  It seems the simplest way to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def coinToss():
    numToss = input("How many times do you want to flip the coin?: ")
    tossList = []
        for element in range(number):
            flip = random.randint(0, 1)
            if flip == 0:
                tossList.append("Heads")
            else:
                tossList.append("Tails")
    print tossList, ": there were %d heads and %d tails" %(tossList.count("Heads"), tossList.count("Tails"))
```

or

```
def coinToss():
    numToss = input("How many times do you want to flip the coin?: ")
    tossList = []
    headCounter = 0
        for element in range(number):
            flip = random.randint(0, 1)
            if flip == 0:
                tossList.append("Heads")
                headCounter += 1
            else:
                tossList.append("Tails")
    print tossList, ": there were %d heads and %d tails" %(headcounter, len(tossList)-headCounter)
```

or

```
def coinToss():
    numToss = input("How many times do you want to flip the coin?: ")
    tossList = []
        for element in range(number):
            tossList.append(random.randint(0, 1))
    print tossList, ": there were %d heads and %d tails" %(tossList.count(1), tossList.count("Tails"))
```

or

```
def coinToss():
    numToss = input("How many times do you want to flip the coin?: ")
    tossList = []
        for element in range(number):
            tossList.append(random.randint(0, 1))
    print tossList, ": there were %d heads and %d tails" %(sum(tossList), tossList.count("Tails"))
```

or

```
def coinToss():
    numToss = input("How many times do you want to flip the coin?: ")
    tossList = [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in xrange(numToss)]
    print tossList, ": there were %d heads and %d tails" %(sum(tossList), tossList.count("Tails"))
```

or

```
def coinToss():
    tossList = [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in xrange(input("How many times do you want to flip the coin?: "))]
    print tossList, ": there were %d heads and %d tails" %(sum(tossList), tossList.count("Tails"))
```